# Using PromiseKit to force sequential download

Tags: ios, objective-c, promise, promisekit

I am using PromiseKit and would like to force sequential download of JSONs. The count of JSONs might change.

I have read [this](http://promisekit.org/chaining/) about chaining.
If I had a fixed number of say 3 downloads, this would be fine.

But what if I had a changing count of download that I would like to download sequentially?

This is my code for 2 URLs. I wonder how I could do this with `dateUrlArray[i]` iteration over the array?

```
 - (void)downloadJSONWithPromiseKitDateArray:(NSMutableArray *)dateUrlArray {
    [self.operationManager GET:dateUrlArray[0]
                    parameters:nil]
    .then(^(id responseObject, AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation) {
        NSDictionary *resultDictionary = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
        Menu *menu = [JsonMapper mapMenuFromDictionary:resultDictionary];
        if (menu) {
            [[DataAccess instance] addMenuToRealm:menu];
        }
        return [self.operationManager GET:dateUrlArray[1]
                               parameters:nil];
    }).then(^(id responseObject, AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation) {
        NSDictionary *resultDictionary = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;

        Menu *menu = [JsonMapper mapMenuFromDictionary:resultDictionary];
        if (menu) {
            [[DataAccess instance] addMenuToRealm:menu];
        }
    })
    .catch(^(NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self handleCatchwithError:error];
        });
    }).finally(^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            DDLogInfo(@".....finally");
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is `then`able chaining. You want to chain multiple promises in a for loop.

My Objective-C is really rusty - but it should look something like:

```
// create an array for the results
__block NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[urls count]];
// create an initial promise
PMKPromise *p = [PMKPromise promiseWithValue: nil]; // create empty promise
for (id url in urls) {
    // chain
    p = p.then(^{
        // chain the request and storate
        return [self.operationManager GET:url
                parameters:nil].then(^(id responseObject, AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation) {
              [results addObject:responseObject]; // reference to result
              return nil; 
        });
    });
}
p.then(^{
    // all results available here
});
```

Comment: Many many thanks for that 'rusty' ObjC ;-)  Great answer, and IMHO an omission on the Promisekit Site.   I did a small edit (p should be of type PMKPromise).

Answer (score 6):

For those of us looking for a **Swift 2.3** solution:

```
import PromiseKit

extension Promise {
    static func resolveSequentially(promiseFns: [()->Promise<T>]) -> Promise<T>? {
        return promiseFns.reduce(nil) { (fn1: Promise<T>?, fn2: (()->Promise<T>)?) -> Promise<T>? in
            return fn1?.then({ (_) -> Promise<T> in
                return fn2!()
            }) ?? fn2!()
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this function returns `nil` if the promises array is empty.

**Example of use**

Below is an example of how to upload an array of attachments in sequence:

```
func uploadAttachments(attachments: [Attachment]) -> Promise<Void> {
    let promiseFns = attachments.map({ (attachment: Attachment) -> (()->Promise<Void>) in
        return {
            return self.uploadAttachment(attachment)
        }
    })
    return Promise.resolveSequentially(promiseFns)?.then({}) ?? Promise()
}

func uploadAttachment(attachment: Attachment) -> Promise<Void> {
    // Do the actual uploading
    return Promise()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input!  BTW: meanwhile I  solve this kind of tasks with NSOperation wgich doesn't require a third party library

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, that totally makes sense!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for Vegard's answer and I rewrite for Swift 3:

```
extension Promise {
    static func resolveSequentially(promiseFns: [()->Promise<T>]) -> Promise<T>? {
        return promiseFns.reduce(nil) { (fn1: Promise<T>?, fn2: (()->Promise<T>)?) -> Promise<T>? in
            return fn1?.then{ (_) -> Promise<T> in
                return fn2!()
            } ?? fn2!()
        }
    }
}



/* Example */
func uploadAttachments(_ attachments: [Attachment]) -> Promise<Void> {
    let promiseFns = attachments.map({ (attachment: Attachment) -> (()->Promise<Void>) in
        return {
            return self. uploadAttachment(attachment)
        }
    })

    return Promise.resolveSequentially(promiseFns: promiseFns)?.then{Void -> Void in} ?? Promise { Void -> Void in }
}
```